# How to Populate Data from a table to another

Tags: excel, vba, adodb

I have 2 tables A & B. A is a summary table and B is a breakdown of table A. I want to achieve that whatever is entered in Table A reflects in Table B.

[image]

```
 ReSql = "INSERT INTO " & XGetListObject(Sheet1.ListObjects(1)) & "([Account?],[count of' 
              'invoices],[value],[Percent]) " & _'
                          '"SELECT [Account?],[count of invoices],[value],[Percent] FROM "'
                                 '& GetListObject(Sheet2.ListObjects(1)) & " as T2"
```

Any idea, please how to achieve this?

Comment: Just curious, is there an important thing so the code must use adodb to achieve the expected result ?

Comment: @karma, no reasons at all as this is a part of a big connection report, so i thought adodb  could get the results faster, but if you have a way, please share it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly:

```
Sub test()
Dim rg As Range, rgF As Range

With Sheets("Sheet1")
Set rg = .Range("A2", .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
End With

With Sheets("Sheet1") 'sheet for result, change if needed
    Set rgF = .Range("F2") 'starting cell result, change if needed
    rgF.Resize(500000, 4).Clear
End With

With rgF.Offset(0, 1)
    .Value = "A01" 'the starting invoice number, change if needed
    .AutoFill Destination:=.Resize(Application.Sum(rg.Offset(0, 1)), 1), Type:=xlFillDefault
    .Resize(Application.Sum(rg.Offset(0, 1)), 1).Offset(0, 2).NumberFormat = "0%"
End With

For Each cell In rg
    Set rgF = rgF.Resize(cell.Offset(0, 1).Value, 1)
    rgF.Value = cell.Value
    rgF.Offset(0, 2).Value = cell.Offset(0, 2).Value / cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
    rgF.Offset(0, 3).Value = cell.Offset(0, 3).Value
    Set rgF = rgF.End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
Next

End Sub
```

The sub is not automatically run. So it need something like a button to be clicked to run the sub. The sub is not doing an addition, but always "rebuild" the whole data for table-2. So, it will always clear first all data in table-2.

It create a  range for account of table-1 as rg variable.
It create a starting cell where the result will be put as rgF variable.
Then it clear all data in table-2.

It fill the starting invoice number to the rgF offset(0,1) - then it fill series based on that invoice number - then it format the last column of table-2 with percent.

Then it loop to each cell in rg, reset the rows of the rgF with the value of cell.offset 0,1. Fill the rgF with the looped cell value, fill the rgF offset 0,2 with the result from dividing and fill rgF offset 0,3 with the percentage.

Comment: apologies for dragging you again to this example, but imagine that, the account list in table B is already there, is there a way you can search by Account number in table B and once it's located insert the values and the percentage from table A?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't quite understand what you mean if I don't see how does it look the table-B, and how does it look table-A. Because if table-B looks like in the image of your question (which already there, not built by the macro), then the percentage also already there in table-B. So, what percentage from table-A to be inserted under the row of the Account in table-B ? Please CMIIW